# como subir solamente el directorio "./build" y no todo el proyecto utilizando travis-ci

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, travis-ci

tengo un proyecto en reactjs y quiero que cuando ejecute el comando `$ git push --tags` se suba en el apartado de release únicamente los archivos que se generan cuando hago un `$ npm run build` y no todo el proyecto.

Esta es mi configuración de travis.yml

```
sudo: required
language: node_js
env:
  global:
    - RELEASE_NAME=build
node_js:
  - "stable"
cache:
directories:
  - node_modules
before_install:
  - npm ci
script:
  - npm run build
deploy:
  provider: releases
  api_key: $GITHUB_TOKEN
  local_dir: ./build
  on:
    branch: master
    tags: true
```

Asi me sale cuando me descargo el archivo en el aportado de release en github 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que necesito es que solo me muestre los siguientes archivos al momento de descargar la release

```
build:
--bundle.css
--bundle.js
--index.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución, lo resolví de la siguiente forma:

```
sudo: required
language: node_js
env:
  global:
    - RELEASE_NAME=build
node_js:
  - "stable"
cache:
directories:
  - node_modules
before_install:
  - npm ci
script:
  - npm run build
before_deploy:
  - tar -czf $RELEASE_NAME-$TRAVIS_TAG.tar.gz $RELEASE_NAME
  - zip -r $RELEASE_NAME-$TRAVIS_TAG.zip $RELEASE_NAME
  - ls -al
deploy:
  provider: releases
  api_key: $GITHUB_TOKEN
  file: 
    - $RELEASE_NAME-$TRAVIS_TAG.tar.gz
    - $RELEASE_NAME-$TRAVIS_TAG.zip
  skip_cleanup: true
  on:
    tags: true
```